# How to print a list of enumerated items in Python

Tags: python, scripting

Let's say I want to create a new bone constraint in a script. Blender then tells me that it wants to know which type of constraint I want to create.

Can I print a list of all possible types? I know I could reverse engineer the names by creating the constraints and reading the types, but I'd like to have a more general solution.

So, is there something like `print(dir())` that does the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, you can print a list like this:

```
print(bpy.types.Constraint.bl_rna.properties["type"].enum_items.keys())
```

But in this case I'd suggest to use Blenders documentation.

*Note that this is Blender specific, Python doesn't provide a way to list possible valid values for an attribute.*

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is an enumeration of available constraints, it's listed in [`bpy.types.Constraint`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.Constraint.html#bpy.types.Constraint) API documentation.