# How do I get Cycles to use GPU on a linux server?

Tags: gpu

Inspired by this question: [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles/7486?noredirect=1#comment121807_7486)

---

I have access to a Linux server that is equipped with GeForce GTX TITAN X. Now Cycles still renders everything with CPU. How can I get it to exploit the GPU?

Since I am talking about a Linux server, I guess there are two steps towards this goal:

1. How to get the GPU ID or identifier with Unix commands so that I can refer to it in Blender?
2. How to use Python to enable GPU computations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For enabling the device for use, see [`bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device_type` and

`bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UserPreferencesSystem.html?highlight=compute_device_type#bpy.types.UserPreferencesSystem.compute_device).

To check these from a shell, put the python you wish to execute in a file and run

```
blender --background --python <file.py>
```

Or, more concisely for quick tests,

```
blender -b --python-expr 'import bpy; <python code here>'
```

For convenience, here's a script which will print the possible and current values of `compute_device_type` and `compute_device`:

```
import bpy

sysp = bpy.context.user_preferences.system

devt = sysp.compute_device_type
dev = sysp.compute_device

# get list of possible values of enum, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2268/599
devt_list = sysp.bl_rna.properties['compute_device_type'].enum_items.keys()
dev_list = sysp.bl_rna.properties['compute_device'].enum_items.keys()

# pretty print
lines=[
("Property", "Value", "Possible Values"),
("Device Type:", devt, str(devt_list)),
("Device:", dev, str(dev_list)),
]
print("\nGPU compute configuration:")
for l in lines:
    print("{0:<20} {1:<20} {2:<50}".format(*l))
```

If `CUDA` shows up in the possible values for device type, then enabling the device should be as simple as doing something like this in python:

```
devt = sysp.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
dev = sysp.compute_device = 'CUDA_0'
```

To find the identifier for the device, you can use the script above with a line to set `compute_device_type` to `CUDA` before getting the list of possible devices.

---

Once that's all enabled we must still tell cycles to actually use it; to do this set [`bpy.context.scene.cycles.device`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=scene%20cycles#bpy.types.Scene.cycles) to `GPU`.

Comment: Very clear answer; +1. For me, `Device Type:         NONE                 ['NONE', 'CUDA'] `. What does this mean? My device type is `None`, and compute device is `CUDA`? Thanks!

Comment: @SibbsGambling Ah, that wasn't layed out very clearly at all. There are two lines, the first is the "device type" property, its current value, and the possible selections (this is for picking between opencl and cuda). The second line shows the selected "device" (which, if device type is none, should also be none). The "device type" will have no option available besides `NONE` if there is a lack of detected devices for either opencl or cuda, so that fact that cuda is an option suggests you are in good shape. I've added headers to the little table printed by the snippet, hopefully that clarifies

Comment: Awesome! So I have devices `['CUDA_MULTI_0', 'CUDA_0', 'CUDA_1', 'CUDA_2', 'CUDA_3']`, and now the GPU gets to run!

Comment: But... why the GPU computation is much slower than the CPU computations to render the same scene?

Comment: @SibbsGambling Sorry about the delay.. [What tile size are you using](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44428/599)? Does a larger size  help (maybe 512)?

Comment: Happy new year! Let me experiment with the tile size a bit. ;)