# Can I use blender with Azure Nvidia K80 to render using GPU

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, command-line

I am using the K80 Nvidia series on Microsoft Azure and when I try to detect available devices using the script on this thread:

[How do I get Cycles to use GPU on a linux server?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70120/how-do-i-get-cycles-to-use-gpu-on-a-linux-server)

I get the following output - I am using Blender 2.78

```
GPU compute configuration:
Property             Value                Possible Values
Device Type:         NONE                 ['NONE']
Device:              CPU                  ['CPU']
```

It seems as though blender is not detecting the GPU - is there a way to force this or is it just a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was facing was caused by the fact that I hadn't followed the correct setup steps:

1) Use the latest LTS Ubuntu image (16.04) - I was using 14.04

2) Install the correct drivers

Details for using GPU on Azure can be found at:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/linux/n-series-driver-setup